# Rails 3 Issue when comment form is before list of comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a comments section on a page. When I put the form below the list of current comments, it works fine. But when I put the form above the list of current comments, I get the error `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`. Here is the form:

```
<% form_for([@person, @person.comments.build], :remote => true) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :comment %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :comment, :required => :true %>
  </div><br />
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Comment" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And the comment list (with the form being rendered):

```
<%= render "comments/form" %>
<div id="comments">
<% @person.comments.each do |comment| %>
<h3><%= comment.user.name %> says</h3>
<p><%= comment.comment %></p>
<p><%= comment.created_at.to_date %> at <%= comment.time_string %></p>
<hr>
<% end %>
```

I have, in `routes.rb`, my comments resource nested as well.

Comment: I have something similar I am working on too. In the first code you mentioned person model and in the second you mentioned it as user model. Is that a typo?

Comment: Should it be `<h3><%= comment.person.name %> says</h3>` instead of `<h3><%= comment.user.name %> says</h3>`

Comment: Actually it is correct. I substituted 'person' for a longer name to keep it readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of `@person.comments.build`. Using this will build new `comments` and associate them to `@person` thus overriding previous `comments` associated to `@person`.

So, I quote you "When I put the form below the list of current comments, it works fine". " But when I put the form above the list of current comments, I get the error `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`".

If you put the form in the first place, `@person.comments.build` gets executed before showing current comments and the previous associated comments are gone. So, when you try to loop over each comment and call `comment.user.name` it errors out, as `comment.user` returns nil.

Do verify that the error is due `<h3><%= comment.user.name %> says</h3>`

Comment: Is there anyway to fix this issue? What should I change to get it to work?

Comment: Try using `@person.comments.new` instead of `build`.

Comment: In my case, `@person.comments.new` did not worked, so I redid the find - `@person = Person.find(params[:id])` before listing or rather rendering the comments.